# Drop down from body in excel sheet

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I want a drop down in my excel sheet using apache poi but the drop down is coming from header and on following rows Can anyone tell me what should be the correct address list?

Comment: Totally unclear. Do you mean applying an [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

Comment: Have you tried creating the drop-down in Excel and comparing that to what you are generating with POI? `XLSX` is a zip file, just change the extension to .zip to look at it. Or, are you using `XLS`?

Comment: Have a look at this reply. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587987/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi)