# Excel dependent drop down list using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I need to create a dependent drop down list for two adjacent columns in XSSFSheet sheet.
Ex:-

Col: Country | State

```
 C1      | [S1,S2,S3]
```

The data would be in Map<String,String[]> format, so when country column is selected from drop down, states array for that selected country needs to be shown in "State" adjacent column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587987/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi/53636333#53636333

Comment: thanks @AxelRichter