# Cascading Dropdowns in Excel using Apache POI - #Name Error Issue

Tags: excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, hidden

I am working on a Java application where I use Apache POI to create Excel sheets with cascading dropdowns. The goal is to dynamically update the dropdown values based on the selection of a higher-level dropdown. However, I am facing an issue with the #Name error in Excel when trying to implement this cascading behavior.

**Implementation Details:**

1. Dropdown Values Retrieval:
   I am retrieving all dropdown values for District, Taluka, and
   Village.
2. Hidden Sheet Creation:
   I am creating a hidden sheet for District, Taluka, and Village.
3. Formulas:
   I am applying the following formulas:

Taluka: `INDIRECT(INDEX(TalukaDropdown, MATCH($E$2, DistrictDropdown, 0)))`

Village: `INDIRECT(INDEX(VillageDropdown, MATCH($F$2, TalukaDropdown, 0)))`

```
DataValidationHelper validationHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
CellRangeAddressList talukaAddressList = new CellRangeAddressList(rowNumber + 1, 1000, talukaColumnIndex, talukaColumnIndex);
DataValidationConstraint talukaConstraint = validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint(talukaFormula);
DataValidation talukaValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(talukaConstraint, talukaAddressList);
```

**Problem Statement:**

While the sheet is generating successfully, the dropdown values for Taluka and Village are displaying #Name instead of the actual values.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve the #Name error and ensure that the dropdown values are displayed correctly.

Comment: I doubt you will get proper answers until you show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is currently too much ambiguity in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587987/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi/53636333#53636333 for a complete example: Copy code / paste / compile / run.